# Pixel formats, CVPixelBufferRefs and glReadPixels

Tags: ios, avassetwriter, glreadpixels

I'm using `glReadPixels` to read data into a `CVPixelBufferRef`. I use the `CVPixelBufferRef` as the input into an `AVAssetWriter`. Unfortunately the pixel formats seem to be mismatched.

I think `glReadPixels` is returning pixel data in **RGBA** format while `AVAssetWriter` wants pixel data in **ARGB** format. What's the best way to convert **RGBA** to **ARGB**?

Here's what I've tried so far:

- bit manipulation along the lines of argb = (rgba >> 8) | (rgba << 24)
- using a `CGImageRef` as an intermediate step

The bit manipulation didn't work because CVPixelBufferRef doesn't seem to support subscripts. The `CGImageRef` intermediate step does work... but I'd prefer not to have 50 extra lines of code that could potentially be a performance hit.

Comment: How are you getting your CVPixelBufferRef?  Are you calling CVPixelBufferCreate?  If so, what are you passing as the pixelFormatType parameter?  What format are you passing to glReadPixels?

Comment: I'm passing `kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB` to `CVPixelBufferCreate`. I pass `GL_RBGA` to `glReadPixels`. I tried passing an RBGA format to `CVPixelBufferCreate` but it didn't work (either bad colors or the app crashed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better than using the CPU to swap the components would be to write a simple fragment shader to efficiently do it on the GPU as you render the image.

And the best bestest way is to completely remove the copying stage by using an iOS5 CoreVideo CVOpenGLESTextureCache which allows you to render straight to the CVPixelBufferRef, eliminating the call to glReadPixels.

p.s. I'm pretty sure AVAssetWriter wants data in BGRA format (actually it probably wants it in yuv, but that's another story).

UPDATE: as for links, the doco seems to still be under NDA, but there are two pieces of freely downloadable example code available:

[GLCameraRipple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Listings/GLCameraRipple_RippleViewController_m.html) and [RosyWriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html)

The header files themselves contain good documentation, and the mac equivalent is very similar (CVOpenGLTextureCache), so you should have plenty to get you started.

Comment: `OpenGLTextureCache` sounds awesome. Have any links to relevant docs?

Comment: if you have an ADC login you can get the docs, added some example code to answer

Comment: Looks really interesting! Thanks :-)

Comment: They're The Way, you'll never look at glReadPixels & glTexImage2D the same way ever again. One caveat, kinda big: I'm pretty sure this stuff has hardware support on the iPad2 (maybe on the 4S too), on lesser hardware the timings suggest that it falls back on glReadPixels/glTexImage2D.

Comment: "And the best bestest way is to completely remove the copying stage by using an iOS5 CoreVideo CVOpenGLESTextureCache which allows you to render straight to the CVPixelBufferRef, eliminating the call to glReadPixels." - can't find any documentation to this much wanted feature

Comment: Read the header file: CVOpenGLESTextureCache.h

Comment: I did, it says: "Creates a CVOpenGLESTexture object from an existing CVImageBuffer". This is the opposite of what we want :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550297/faster-alternative-to-glreadpixels-in-iphone-opengl-es-2-0

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the bit manipulation, you can get a pointer to the pixel buffer's raw data:

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);
size_t stride = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(buffer);
char *data = (char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer);
for (size_t y = 0; y < CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buffer); ++y) {
    uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t *)(data + stride * y);
    for (size_t x = 0; x < CVPixelBufferGetWidth(buffer); ++x)
        pixels[x] = (pixels[x] >> 8) | (pixels[x] << 24);
}
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a shot in the dark, but have you tried `GL_BGRA` for `glReadPixels` with `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` for `CVPixelBufferCreate`?

I suggest this because [Technical Q&A QA1501](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1501/_index.html) doesn't list any RGBA format as supported.

Comment: Unfortunately passing GL_BGRA to `glReadPixels` causes the output pixel data to be all zero :-(

Answer (score 1):

glReadPixels(0, 0, w*s, h*s, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

Use GL_BGRA in glReadPixels.
It works, just tried it myself.

Comment: Did you get non-zero data in the output buffer?

Answer (score 1):

```
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _buffer);
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
    CVReturn ret = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,_size.width,_size.height,kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,glubyte,_size.width*4,NULL,NULL,NULL,&buffer);
```